# laravel api displays error Target class does not exist on production (cpanel)

Tags: laravel, api

I deployed my laravel api to cpanel

but I am getting this error

```
Target class [App\http\Controllers\EmployeesController] does not exist.
```

even though the controller is in the correct folder

It works fine on localhost but on cpanel(production) it displays the error

api.php

```
Route::resource('/employees', EmployeesController::class);
Route::resource('/companies', CompaniesController::class);
Route::resource('/contacts', ContactsController::class);
Route::resource('/managers', ManagersController::class);
```

Comment: please check php version in cpanel. I can't find any `EmployeesController` in your code

Comment: Could it be that `http` is spelled with a lowercase h rather than `Http`? `Use App\Http\Controllers\EmployeesController;`

Comment: @A.ANoman my php version is 7.3. I have updated my code. Thanks